# Trying to find RDP Certification, not showing cert manager

Tags: remote-desktop, certificate

I connected to a machine via RDP, and I'm wondering where I can find the RDP certification.
I checked certlm.msc and certmgr.msc, I used the 'Find' action and nothing pops up when entering the name of the Cert image below:

[image]

Do I need to install the certificate for it to show in cert manager?

[image]

Comment: What has led you to believe that you require a certificate (it is a "certificate", which "certifies", and is a "certification", but the word you mean to use is probably "certificate") for this RDP connection? Are you actually experiencing a real problem, or is the only issue that you're expecting something that you do not see?

Comment: "Do I need to install the certificate for it to show in cert manager?" - Yes; You actually need to also install any certificates signed by the Root Certificate.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks for your input. I have a better understanding now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatically generated RDP certificates do show up under `certlm.msc` as machine certificates – but not under "Personal"; they have a separate section specifically for "Remote Desktop".

Note that this is on the **remote** computer, because you're viewing the remote computer's certificate. Your client computer *does not store* collected remote certificates anywhere – they're received every time a connection is made and forgotten afterwards.

[image]